# Important difference between article and book documentclass

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, books, article, tikz-decorations

I have lots of tex files that run normally in `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}` and when I'm trying to put them all in `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}`, with `\include{part1}` etc. it shows a message like:

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/\pgfkeyscurrent

The problem started when I added `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}` to the preamble, but it was necessary for some tikz constructions (and as I previously mentioned, it works fine as an article).

If I close texmaker and then open it again, it seems to the pdf view as it had been run normally.

**Edit:**

Both article and book documentclass preambles include the following packages:

```
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[mathup=sym]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds,patterns,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,svg.path,shapes.geometric,shadows}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{shadowtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,theorems,skins,raster,xparse,breakable}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
```

Comment: book or article have absolutely no effect on tikz/pgf. You must be loading pgf with different options,. but as you have shown no code it is hard to help.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that each part1 etc. file has its own preamble.  The subfile package was intended to handle this sort or arrangement.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I have just edited my question for the case it helps.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have just edited my question for the case it helps.

Comment: No you still have not provided any example of your problem. It's impossible to help with the just  information you have provided so far.

Comment: Compiling that preamble with book or article gives the same thing.  Please show us some code that you think should run the same, but is running differently.

Comment: please remove all the unrelated packages but provide a complete small document that works with `article` but gives the error shown if you change `article` to `book`

Comment: How can I know where the "error message" refers to? It's a whole book with over 70000 code lines.

Comment: the error message (which you have not shown) will have the line number and looking at the log you can tell which file it is.

Comment: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/\pgfkeyscurrent

Comment: Copy everything over to a new project, and start deleting all of your document that isn't related to this question.  Then start deleting all of your preamble that isn't related to this question.  You should be able to get it down to 10-20 lines that is entirely self contained.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it refers to the following line code, that includes in the last file I imported to the book: \draw [
    thick, below,
    decoration={
        brace,
    },
    decorate
] (3.7,-0.15) -- (0.7,-0.15) 
node [pos=0.5,below] {$Α$};

Comment: so make an example based on that that shows the error with book but not with article. We honestly can not help without that as the behaviour is not expected: it is due to something in your document you have not shown

Comment: "Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/\pgfkeyscurrent – " is just a fragment of the error message the full message will have line number and some context lines showing where tex is at the point of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A minimal working example ([mwe](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/79060)) would make this question answerable for more community members I think.)

You need to load tikz library [`decorations.pathreplacing`](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#pgf.decorations.pathreplacing) to use decoration `brace` (`\draw [..., decoration={brace}, ...]`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick, below, decoration={brace}, decorate]
    (3.7,-0.15) -- (0.7,-0.15) node[pos=0.5,below] {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Background info**

The provided error message

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/\pgfkeyscurrent

is both incomplete and incorrect. Its full form should be

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/\pgfkeyscurrentname ' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

and its incorrectness was caused by a tikz bug https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1082. pgf-tikz v3.10.0 tried to fix it, but only made it to another ill form.

When using `\draw[..., decoration={brace}, ...]` without loading `decorations.pathreplacing` library, the expected full error message is

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/brace', to which you passed '', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

if any decoration library except `decorations.pathreplacing` is loaded, otherwise you will get errors

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/decoration', to which you passed 'brace', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
> [...]
> ! Package tikz Error: You need to load a decoration library.

Comment: muzimuzhi Z (It doesn't let me tag your name) your answer was perfect and the problem solved. I'm trying to formulate my questions as much as better I can, but in this case it was more difficult to write an example, and my bad English don't help me as well.

Comment: @GSpyros Happy TeXing!

Comment: @GSpyros I don't think it was your English as much as it was you not wanting to spend the effort to isolate what was causing the error.

Comment: @Teepeemm I have already answered to this. What could I do more? It's a book of 600 pages and over 70000 code lines. Now, if your point is to make me prove that I'm not an elephant, what can I say more...